# Sitecore ser push fails - You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

Sitecore serialization is no longer working on production, every attempt results in "You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions". It was working before, but is now failing with the same error in both Jenkins and in Powershell. I reviewed all the steps on https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/configure-a-non-interactive-client-login.html and everything appears to still be configured correctly.

I've reviewed all the related issues I can find but have not found anything about the same issue because 1. the error does not occur on login, the login works but it fails on sitecore ser push. 2. it is not just with non-interactive login, it fails for interactive login in powershell too.

- requiresUniqueEmail is set to false
- PasswordStrengthRegularExpression is not present in the web.config

[image]

Comment: Double check that identityServerAuthority variable on CM matches your SI domain you try to log in through CLI with. (...-si.azurewebsites.net in your case).

Comment: you mean the server name? I checked the configuration files on CM and SI and everything matches. It wouldn't lot in successfully if they didn't, right?

Comment: Have you checked this related post?: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35253/sitecore-cli-not-authorized-to-perform-the-task-you-are-attempting-no-sitecore

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert Unfortunatelly not, it would let you log in through CLI and then throw error like you have if Sitecore variable identityServerAuthority on CM is not same as --authority domain that is used in CLI to authenticate. Weird behaviour, but according to Sitecore it is expected. Worth to check Identity Server and CM logs for potential errors.

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert check the `identityServerAuthority` value in `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`